# Índices compostos x simples numa tabela MySQL com um grande volume de dados

Tags: mysql, índices, big-data

Fala pessoal blz?

Tow com uma dúvida que na documentação do MySQL não é muito clara. Fala lá qual a diferença de um índice composto e outro simples. Até aí tudo bem.

Minha dúvida é se numa tabela com milhões de registros, é mais vantajoso criar índices compostos ou simples para cada campo que vai ser usado na busca.

Por exemplo numa tabela com a seguinte estrutura de campos:

**id, local_id, nome, cpf, telefone, ativo**, etc...

Faremos consultas pegando por:

- **local_id AND nome AND ativo**
- **nome AND ativo**
- **local_id AND cpf AND ativo**
- **cpf AND nome AND ativo**
- **local_id AND ativo**

Seria vantajoso em termos de performance se criássemos aí 5 índices compostos, mesmo repetindo campos da tabela, ou seria mais vantajoso criar os índices para cada campo. Lembrando que a tabela terá milhões de regitros.

Alguém já viveu essa realidade na prática?

Poderia me dar uma orientação quanto a isso?

Vlw.

Comment: A questão é definir o número de ocorrências retornado nas pesquisas , cpf e nome "desempatam" o alto retorno provável de local_id , sendo desnecessário em tese , local_id e ativo deve retornar tantos valores que a "full table" talvez seja mais barata. Dependendo do volume da pesquisa vale sim o custo de ser criar índices mesmo eles custado nas operações de CRUD , mas a resposta neste caso é sempre DEPENDE , DEPENDE ...

Answer (score -2):

Temos sempre que lembrar que na criação de um índices o SQL server ocupa mais espaço de armazenamento e terá mais custos de I/O e CPU nas realizações de update e insert.

Índices só são criados em dados com cláusulas where, nesse exemplo que vc sugeriu seria interesante um mapeamento de qual cláusula where mais se utiliza para assim a criação de índice.

Outra sugestão quando temos milhões de dados é possível a criação de filtered Index que são index criados a partir de uma clausua where, nesse exemplo caso os dados mais acessados fossem os ativos = 1 por exemplo, seria interessante a criação de index só nos dados que possuem isso, por exemplo dava para vc criar

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nome_index
ON nome_tabela (local_id)
WHERE Ativo = 1;

Ele aloca espaço de armazenamento no banco apenas nesses dados, então pode ser uma estratégia interessante. caso queira saber mais tem a documentação aqui.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-filtered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).